# Set classpath with a java program?

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I want to set this `C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program` as a classpath with java program. How can I do that?

Comment: I doubt you know what you want to do. WHY would anyone want this in his classpath and does not know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry guys i edited my question!

Comment: The answers belwo show you: YOU CAN'T DO THAT. And we all don't really understand what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Its not much use modifying the classpath after JVM startup, as that system property has already been read by the runtime during intialization and your changes will have no effect.

I recommend using scripts to modify your classpath before initializing java

Comment: what ?? did u understand my question?

Comment: perhaps you should consider explaining it better

Comment: @Harinder: I dont blame `qwerty`. Your question reads as if you want a java program to set the classpath.

Comment: +1 for this is the only answer so far that matches the question: how set a classpath *with* a java program. And the note, that this doesn't make sense (for the actual running jvm) is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

add `-classpath C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program` to your java command

Comment: what do i write in a program?

Comment: If you use this approach, you have to include `-classpath C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program` everytime you type the command `java`. Look at my answer .. Use Environmental variable concept.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `My Computer > right click > Properties > Advance Tab > Environment variable > System variable > New.`

Add

```
   Name : CLASSPATH  
   Value : C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program
```

Comment: Please show some respect by commenting the reason for downvote, fellow Stacker ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a fixed class path in your application and you want to load classes from `C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program` (which might be a path configured by the user of your application at runtime), you can use

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
    new File("C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program").toURI().toURL()
});
classLoader.loadClass("com.mycompany.FooBar");
```

to load the class `com.mycompany.FooBar`.